# Bidirectional selection

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have 3 charts: a choropleth chart, row chart and a select menu. All three have the states of my country and the first two graphs show the number of people per state.

I had to create three times the same dimension and groups to have interactivity between them. If I click on the map in the states A, B and C, they highlight in the row chart and vice versa if I select the states in the rowchart appear on the map.

The problem I have is that the selection is only in one direction, if I already selected the states A, B and C in the rowchart and on the map I want to select the state D everything is gray and with values 0.
Is it possible to be bidirectional ?, or even between the three graphs.

Thank you so much.
Best regards.

Comment: It did not let me put the salute at the beginning. Hello everyone

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is is one dimension which is shared across all three charts, with [one linked selection between them](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/681). It's kind of annoying and tricky to implement this outside of the library, but it can be done - you kind of tie the `filter` functions together - you need all three to hear when the selection changes, but only apply the filter once. Sorry I don't have better advice.

Comment: thank you, I found just one example developed by you [https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/yodzpnsL/10/]
Shows me what i need